# How can I create a browser shortcut to append a parameter to current URL and then load the resulting url?

Tags: javascript, browser, shortcut

I want to create shortcut in my browser which will append a url before the current URL and then reload the new URL in the same tab. Say I am visiting espn.com. Then I want to be able to to click on the shortcut so that the url becomes stackoverflow.com/espn.com and loads that page.

I am complete novice in Javascript so I have no clue how it works except that I have a similar shortcut on my browser that works exactly like this. I have read other similar answers but I was not able to make head or tail of it. The current shortcut that I am using takes a current reddit.com comment page and opens it in reddit-stream.com by converting the link. The code for the shortcut is as follows:

javascript:(function%20stream()%20%7Bvar%20s%20=%20window.location.href.split('/');var%20id%20=%20s%5Bs.indexOf('comments')+1%5D;if(s.indexOf('comments')%20!=%20-1)%20%7B%20window.location.href%20=%20'http://reddit-stream.com/comments/'%20+%20id;%20%7D%7D)();

The code above doesn't perform the exact function so I can't simply modify it but I hope someone who knows Javascript will be able to write the new code.

Edit: Just to be clear the above code that I have put here already works. I added the code to show what kind of shortcut I was looking for. But all I need is that when I am on website1.com, I click the shortcut and it takes me to website2.com/website1.com where website2.com is always the same website and website1.com changes according to what webpage I am visiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `URL` has been encoded to `normal` string, this does not a valid javascript syntax.

Edit you bookmark with url input exactly the same string above:

```
javascript:(function stream() { var s = window.location.href.split('/'); var id = s[s.indexOf('comments') + 1]; if (s.indexOf('comments') != -1) { window.location.href = 'http://reddit-stream.com/comments/' + id; } })();
```

`javascript:` prefix is very important.

For you case:

```
javascript: (function() {
  var currentDomain = window.location.hostname;
  window.location.href = 'http://website2.com/' + currentDomain;
})();
```

if you want get current path of `website1.com` (like `website1.com/ping`), 
you could use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location.hostname` .

Comment: Hey, thanks this does work but reddit-stream shortcut was already working. What I wanted was to create a new shortcut that had nothing to do with reddit. I want to be able to go to website1.com and click on the shortcut so that it takes me to website2.com/website1.com. I am sorry I was not clear earlier.